# How to install sudo, when I don't have sudo or su

Tags: sudo, docker, root, su

I'm operating within a Kong API Gateway Docker container, and am trying to install some basic package handling. Ultimately, I need to be able to use `sudo`. The Docker image comes with *only* busybox bin commands, located in `/bin/`.

## What I've Tried

I find myself in a pickle, because every guide that explains downloading apt-get uses `sudo`, and every guide I find downloading `sudo` uses `apt-get`. I have neither sudo nor apt and apt-get.

If I try to utilize `su`, `su -`, `su - <cmd>`, or the likes, I get "must be suid to work properly".

## What's Available

This is every command available, located in /bin:

[image: list of every command available]

---

With `wget`, or the above commands, how can I get `sudo`?

Comment: Have you considered editing the Dockerfile to add the sudo package? Err-- nevermind sudo; if you want other packages, can't you just edit the Dockerfile?

Comment: I suppose I could... I'm new to Docker as well, so I'm `exec`'ing in my container to find out what I need to do with the Dockerfile. Would I just have `RUN <install sudo here>`?

Comment: Perhaps we can rescue the question by taking it in the right direction. You're operating within a Docker container. Do you have the ability to create a new container?

Comment: I do! I have a Dockerfile with `FROM kong:2.0-ubuntu` and exposing 5432

Comment: Yes you can do the install with RUN. However you won't need `sudo` if you are still root though. Just install and configure, before switching from root.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you got `sudo` onto your system (easy), it would not help. It needs to be setuid-root to work. And you can't set that up, without root access.

If running the commands without `sudo` is not working, then it is because the Dockerfile has `USER` line. If you edit the Dockerfile, to put the `apt-get` (or the commands to install `apt-get`) before this line, then it will be able to install (you will still be root).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You seem super knowledgeable in this... Is there a way to get `sudo` in without rebuilding the image? I'm running into some severe issues with Kong's official image, and it would be nice to just bypass that and `exec` into the container to add and move files around so that I can get my testing environment running for developing plugins

Comment: More info: The core programs I need are `cp` and `mv`, with or without `sudo`. I'm trying to simply move and edit configuration files that come with the Kong image

Comment: Rebuilding images is not as hard as you may think, and if the changes are late on, then they don't even rebuild. Each line of the Dockerfile creates a layer. It will start on an existing layer, and add more. What image are you using?

Comment: I'm using kong:latest - https://hub.docker.com/_/kong ... With that, the problem I'm hitting with building from a Docker file is the COPY command is unsuccessfully copying my config files, no errors given

Comment: you need to put the `docker-entrypoint.sh` (see https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/tree/fe2f5db88f0eb7c442ba8940027ac51c4ff4da2c/ubuntu ) next to the Dockerfile, then do the docker build.

Comment: I think for the ubunu version (as it leaves you as root), you don't need to rebuild it. You can do a From in your own Dockerfile. You may want to switch user at the end of your Dockerfile.

Comment: That worked! Though it didn't solve my specific problem, this has made me realize I definitely am behind the curve with this stuff, as I'm coming from front-end only experience. I'll go ahead and mark this as an answer since this scope is kind of creeping out from the original question ...

Comment: If you don't have any Kong prior-knowledge, but was able to find out about the docker-entrypoint.sh, what kind of "searchable topic" should I be googling to understand the process of starting a Kong container for plugin development here?

Comment: Good question. I searched for "Kong API Gateway Docker container" -- from your question, and selected the docker hub record ( https://hub.docker.com/_/kong ). I then clicked the version that you said, I found everything there. I also knew that there is always an ently-point, usually a shell script.